# I need an example of how to use a Javascript timer to find out when a user has created a new facebook event.

Tags: javascript, facebook-fql

I'm new to facebook development and coding in general. I know there are currently no real time updates for the event object and that I somehow have to figure out how to poll facebooks servers using javascript. Is there an example of this anywhere? My app is dependent on knowing when a new event has been created so the app can grab its info.

Comment: If you have a single request working, tie it into a setInterval function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use the global setTimeout() function.